# BufferedWriter not writing the array

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedwriter

I have used a buffered writer to write the contents in an array to a text file

```
try {
    File file = new File("Details.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


    for (String line : customer) {
      bw.write(line); //line 178
      bw.newLine();
    }

    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `customer[]` array is as follows:

```
String customer[] = new String[10];
customer[1]="Anne";
customer[2]="Michelle";
```

But when I try writing to the file I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at HotelFunctions.storeData(CustomerMenu.java:178)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:38)
```

I found out that the error is caused because `customer[0]` is null.  I want to avoid the null elements and only write the elements that have string content. Is there a way to handle this error?

Comment: put a check inside your loop for null elements and don't write them. the title of your question is misleading, the problem is not that bufferedwriter is not writing.  it's that you're giving it an invalid argument.

Comment: You should eliminate the problem when you fill your customer Array by ensuring that there is a valid string in the element located at index 0 of your array (customer[0] = "Anne";).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things. First, array indices start at 0, not 1. You should start at `customer[0]`.

```
customer[0] = "Anne";
customer[1] = "Michelle";
```

Second, you could check for null. That's one way.

```
for (String line: customer) {
    if (line != null) {
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

A better way is to use an `ArrayList` instead of a raw array. Arrays are fixed size collections. If you want to have a varying number of elements an `ArrayList` will suit you better. You won't have to guard against null elements. If you add two customers, the list will have two entries, not ten.

```
List<String> customers = new ArrayList<>();

customers.add("Anne");
customers.add("Michelle");

for (String customer: customers) {
    bw.write(customer);
    bw.newLine();
}
```

(By the way, I encourage you to use the naming scheme I did above. Regular variables are singular while arrays and lists use the plural: `customers` is a list, and each element is a `customer`.)

Answer (score 1):

By default array of objects (like Strings) are filled with `null` values. So with

```
String customer[] = new String[10];
customer[1]="Anne";
customer[2]="Michelle";
```

you are ending with array like `[null, "Anne", "Michelle", null, null, ..., null]`.

Now, code of `write` method looks like:

```
public void write(String str) throws IOException {
    write(str, 0, str.length());
}
```

so when you are passing `null` (String array is by default filled with `null`s) `str.length()` ends up as `null.length()` which is invalid since `null` doesn't have any methods nor fields and NPE is thrown.

If you want to skip `null` elements you can simply test them with `==` or `!=` like

```
for (String line : customer) {
    if (line != null){
        bw.write(line); 
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```